# How make an view over other app like musixmatch ? android

Tags: android

I want to make a view that can drag, drop, resize, expand, collapse and display over other app that like Musixmatch. Streenshot:

[image]

have any idea?

Comment: Asking for Idea without Money ? Jokes a part, Share ur approach so others can guide u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article, it may be what you're looking for:
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Basically you need to include the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`, and draw a system Window, placing your content within that window.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I'll try it!